# C# Webservice with Windows application

Tags: c#, web-services, t-sql

I created a simple webservice in C# that returns a table with all the values which is called from a SQL Stored Procedure. I need a little help I wanted to implement a search Textbox for my datagridview in my windowsform application. How could I pass the @search in the storedprocedure to my windows application and send the value back to the stored procedure? Also if I am approaching this the wrong way please let me know Thanks.

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ORCA"].ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getcardinfo", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

As of right now this populates the datagridview just fine. Would like to get it so you can search and that record displays in the datagridview.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your web method into parameter

```
[WebMethod] 
public List<clubmembers> GetClubMembers(String search)
```

add statement before try catch

```
SqlParameter paramSearch = new SqlParameter ("@search",SqlDbType.VarChar);
paramSearch.Value = search;
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSearch);
```